# jQuery Datatable, saving state of the table like pagination, search etc

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination, savestate

So I am using this attribute "bStateSave": true to save the state of jQuery Datatable but for some reason it doesn't work for me. It doesn't save search results and pagination etc when I do the page refresh. Is there some other parameter that needs to go in hand with this one. I am mainly going by the information on this page

http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

The code is too freaking huge to be posted and I am not sure what snipped should I used to post. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I use it as well, and I don't have any problems. Try checking your cookies.  Can you at least post your dataTable() call in your javascript code?

Answer (score 9):

First off, you want to make sure you have a cookie, hop into chrome once you loaded your page, click on "settings," then "show advanced settings," under the privacy section click on content settings.

Below is a code example from that site, that works fine in my web app and also make sure you have the most recent version of the plugin.

```
$('#MyExampleGrv').dataTable({
    "bStateSave": true,
    "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
        localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData));
    },
    "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
        var data = localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname);
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```

What this code does, is makes a local storage instead of the cookie, and uses a page specific versus just using a generic identifier called Datatables, this way if you have a table on another page, there will be no conflicts. What this code will not do, this code will not save the pagination state if you are using ASP.NET controls and a gridview, if you use the generic CRUD operations built into ASP.NET such as EDIT/DELETE/UPDATE, and your edit item is on pagination page 3, it will default to page 1 after postback and even partial postback via AJAX.

Comment: Small warning.  This method could slowly fill up local storage over time if your web site/app URLs are restful.  You might want to enhance this code to remove any IDs from the `window.location.pathname`.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this answer is not about this old version of datatables, but I believe it will help newcomers.

Datatables API changed a lot from 2011 to now.
To save the state of a datatable, you use either HTML5 LocalStorage or DB(ajax callbacks).
To enable state saving using localStorage, you do the following call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#datatable').DataTable({
  stateSave: true,
 });
} );
```

If you want to use **sessionStorage** instead of **localStorage**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#datatable').DataTable({
  stateSave: true,
  stateDuration:-1 //force the use of Session Storage
 });
} );
```

If you want to use a database to avoid storing them in the browser, then you have to use callback functions  defined in the options [stateSaveCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) and [stateLoadCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback).

Here is a tutorial with examples and source code that shows you how to implement all the methods above: [Datatables state save client and server-side](http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-state-save-client-server-side/)

Comment: Worked like a charm for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the cookie when inspecting in your browser?  I am using Chrome and the developer tools to see the current cookies for the link you sent.  I see a cookie called "datatables.net" stored on my machine.  Do you see this cookie when trying your custom DataTables code?

Comment: So I try this alert(dojo.cookie("datatables.net")) and it says "undefined". What does this mean ? There are no cookies being set ? But I thought, internally, that's what the API does, it sets the cookies and then read it to save the state of the table.

Comment: @user1006072 If you can use the extension Firecookie from Firefox it will tell you more.  You should see something like this: SpryMedia_DataTables_<web page> with a full breakdown.  Bottom line is something is blocking this cookie.  Try different browsers to see if there is any change.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for the new version.
Thanks @tgarrett for your solution. And this is also the same as your solution.

```
$('#MyExampleGrv').dataTable({
    stateSave: true,
    stateSaveParams: function (settings, data) {
        localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    stateLoadParams: function (settings) {
        var data = localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname);
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
});
```