# How to return the specific page in jQuery Datatables paging?

Tags: jquery

I have a datable and "Edit" button in each row. When I click that button, /edit/ url opens. Everything is Ok until now. But if I need to go back to the datatable, it starts from the first page. What can I do for that?

```
 $('#table').dataTable({
        "sDom" : 'rtFip>',
        'fnDrawCallback' : function() {
            $('input:checkbox, input:radio').checkbox();
        },
        'sPaginationType' : 'full_numbers',
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "{% url 'get_menu_list' %}"
  });
```

Comment: what a vague question. should we use our imagination?

Comment: Post the code of the button and the dataTable initialization.  Have you also tried asking in the dataTables forums?  http://datatables.net/forums/

Comment: Yes, I asked there also.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

DataTables has option to store state in a cookie.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "stateSave": true
    } );
} );
```

http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

Comment: Yep, no luck in Chrome. Does anybody know if this has been fixed in a later version? I'm on 1.10.9.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the version of Chrome you are using. I'm using Chrome Version 45.0.2454.93 (64-bit) on LInux openSUSE 13.2, and it's working. Though I've not tried it with dataTables version 1.10.9; I'm still using dataTable version 1.10.7

Comment: And what if i want to return to specific row on page? how is it possible

Comment: Great! but that's not all folks, this will store data in localstorage, if you want it to be in session storage or DB here is some more info from this other user https://stackoverflow.com/a/38442163/2914407 for me localstorage  messed things up in reactjs

Answer (score 5):

Storing the state in a cookie fails for large tables. This local storage solution works for large tables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables', JSON.stringify(oData) );
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('DataTables') );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Source: http://datatables.net/blog/localStorage_for_state_saving

Answer (score 4):

**How to return the specific page in jQuery Datatables paging?**

Use `fnPagingInfo`

*Get information about the paging settings that DataTables is currently using to display each page, including the number of records shown, start and end points in the data set etc.*

```
      $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
      {
        return {
          "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
          "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
          "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
          "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
          "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
          "iPage":          Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
          "iTotalPages":    Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
        };
      };


      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
      "fnDrawCallback": function () {
      alert( 'Now on page'+ this.fnPagingInfo().iPage );
      }
      } );
      } );
```

Source: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api

Answer (score 2):

Here is [how to do it](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) in v1.10.7:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        stateSave: true
     } );
} );
```