# Is it possible to integrate the jQuery DataTables plugin into a Silex application with doctrine 2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, datatables, silex, service-provider

I want to integrate jQuery DataTables into a Silex application with Doctrine 2.

Is there any dedicated service provider or object for that? I'm looking for something similar to this bundle (Symfony2):

https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`DatatablesProvider.php`](https://gist.github.com/ooXei1sh/a515800bb478bd0fed0c)

Create `DatatablesServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace Dev\Pub\Provider;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Dev\Pub\Provider\DatatablesProvider;

class DatatablesServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Application $app)
    {
        $app['datatables'] = $app->share(function ($app){
            $datatables = new DatatablesProvider();
            return $datatables;
        });
    }

    public function boot(Application $app)
    {
    }
}
```

Register service provider

```
$app->register(new Dev\Provider\DatatablesServiceProvider());
```

Setup the route and controller

```
$app->match('/doctrine-datatables', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

        // view data config - hardcoded :(
        $labels[] = '';
        $columns[] = array('db' => 'id','dt' => 0);

        $data = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'text1',
                'label' => 'Text 1',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'text2',
                'label' => 'Text 2',
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'text3',
                'label' => 'Text 3',
            ),
        );

        foreach($data as $i => $column) {
            $labels[] = $column['label'];
            $columns[] = array(
                'db' => $column['name'],
                'dt' => $i+1
            );
        }

        $view = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'columns' => $columns,
            'filter' => array(),
        );

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

            $datatables = $app['datatables'];

            // gets
            $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();
            $urlparts = parse_url($requestUri);
            parse_str($urlparts['query'], $gets);

            $response = $datatables::simple($gets, $app['orm.em'], 'Dev\Pub\Entity\Form', 'id', $view);
            // error_log(print_r($response,1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);

            return new JsonResponse($response);
        }
        else {

            $em = $app['orm.em'];

            // @note: this should be in a repository
            $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $placeholder = 'o';
            $select = '';
            foreach($view['columns'] as $column) {
                $select .= $placeholder.'.'.$column['db'].',';
            }
            $select = rtrim($select, ',');
            $qb
                ->select($select)
                ->from('Dev\Pub\Entity\Form', $placeholder)
            ;
            $data = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

            return new Response($app['twig']->render('doctrine.html.twig',array(
                'columnLables' => $view['labels'],
                'data' => $data,
            )));
        }

})->bind('doctrine_datatables');
```

Create the Twig view

```
<h2>{{ 'Doctrine'|trans }}</h2>
<hr>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datatables" class="datatables table table-striped table-condensed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                {# render table head field names #}
                {% for label in columnLables %}
                    <th>
                        <p class="text-left">{{ label }}</p>
                    </th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Setup javascripts

```
$(function(){
    console.log('doctrine.main.js');

    // http://www.datatables.net/examples/index
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400459/how-to-return-the-specific-page-in-jquery-datatables-paging
    var $dt = $('.datatables')

        // before ajax request
        .on('preXhr.dt', function ( e, settings, data ) {
            // console.log('before xhr');
            // @todo: validate session id
            // data.sessionId = $('#sessionId').val();
        })

        .dataTable({
            'pagingType': 'simple_numbers',
            'scrollX': true,
            'language': {
                'lengthMenu': ' _MENU_ ',
                'search': '<form class="" role="search"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group">_INPUT_<div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></div></div></div></form>',
                'info': '<p class="lead no-margin"><small>Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries</small></p>'
            },
            'dom': '<"row dataTables_toolbar dataTables_toolbar_top"<"col-md-6"<"fg-toolbar"l>><"col-md-6"<"fg-toolbar text-right search"f>>>t<"row dataTables_toolbar dataTables_toolbar_bottom"<"col-md-6"<"fg-toolbar"i>><"col-md-6"<"fg-toolbar text-right"p>>>',
            'processing': true,
            'serverSide': true,
            // 'deferRender': true,
            'ajax': '/doctrine-datatables',
            'createdRow': function (row, data, index) {

                var
                    id = data[0], // assumes index zero is the id
                    prefix = 'dev_pub_formentitytype_forms_'
                ;

                // add id to tr tag
                $(row).attr('data-entity-id', id);

                // // add checkbox input
                // var checkbox = $('#' + prefix + id).clone();
                // $(':first-child', row).html(checkbox);
            }
        }),

        // datatables api object
        api = $dt.DataTable()
    ;

});
```